# Which algorithm does ES6 Array.find() use

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have looked around but cannot find anywhere that states which algorithm Array.find() uses. Is it a simple loop or maybe a Binary search?

I guess it's different for each JS engine but there must be a consensus on how this function works.

Comment: The algorithm should be the same across all implementations - the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.find) requires it.

Comment: OK thanks for some reason couldn't find this in the spec. Anyway looks like it does a simple loop to test the predicate on each iteration.

Comment: Even theoretically, binary search would only be possible if the item searched for *and* the array in question contained integers or strings that were already sorted.

Comment: Yes true, I was trying to think how a binary search would work on a generic predicate and came to the same conclusion but I also thought that the implementer of the spec will probably be alot more clever than me.

Comment: Even if the spec did not prescribe the algorithm, a binary search would not make much sense, since it would be slower than a linear search. Plus, a binary search would not work in all situations, whereas a linear search always works.